# Make slideToggle check if div is already open, before loading ajax content into it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load, toggle

Excuse me for I am a javascript beginner and I need some help with a task which is probably really banal, although I've searched for a solution here and didn't find any that I could apply to my case.

I have three buttons. When clicked, each slide-opens a div layer and loads content from an external html file into it.

The problem is that after you click one of them, when you click the next one, it first collapses the div, before loading the content. What I would want is for it to simply change the content of the div, if the div is already open. If not, then to open it first.

And I still want it to be toggle-able, in a way that if you click the same link twice, it closes.

I don't know if I am explaining this correctly so here is a pen, hopefully you will see what I mean:

https://codepen.io/tinat/pen/MvjpJW

HTML:

```
<a id="first" href="javascript:void;">
  First
</a>

<a id="second" href="javascript:void;">
  Second
</a>

<a id="third" href="javascript:void;">
  Third
</a>

<div id="description">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#first").click(function(){
    $("#description").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#description").load("https://codepen.io/tinat/pen/PKGpQy.html #description1");
});

$("#second").click(function(){
    $("#description").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#description").load("https://codepen.io/tinat/pen/PKGpQy.html #description2");
});

$("#third").click(function(){
    $("#description").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#description").load("https://codepen.io/tinat/pen/PKGpQy.html #description3");
});
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add `active` class to recognize current active tab, and you can check `active` to determine show content or slide it up.

html

```
    <a class="listen" id="first" href="https://codepen.io/tinat/pen/PKGpQy.html #description1">
         First
    </a>

    <a class="listen" id="second" href="https://codepen.io/tinat/pen/PKGpQy.html #description2">
         Second
     </a>

    <a class="listen" id="third" href="https://codepen.io/tinat/pen/PKGpQy.html #description3">
         Third
     </a>

    <div id="description">
    </div>
```

js

```
    $(".listen").click(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass("active")){
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#description").slideDown("slow");
        $(this).siblings(".listen").removeClass("active");
            $("#description").load($(this).attr("href"));   
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $("#description").slideUp("slow");
      }
      return false;
      });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zt11vkz6/

Comment: I like both of the proposed solutions. I'll definitely use one of them. Thanks heaps guys/girls :)

Answer (score 1):

Updated CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzKpRd).

You will have to keep track of the active tab if the same HTML element is going to be used for each "description". Here I've used the variable `tabId` to track this state and created a function `onClick` to prevent repeating code for each tab.

```
var tabId = null;

function onClick(id, url) {
  if (tabId == id) {
      // We've must have clicked again on the active
      // tab so close description
      $("#description").slideToggle("slow");
      tabId = null;
    } else {
      $("#description").load(url);
      if (tabId == null) {
        // There is no active tab so open description
        $("#description").slideToggle("slow");
      }
      tabId = id;
    }
}

$("#first").click(function(){
  onClick(1, "https://codepen.io/tinat/pen/PKGpQy.html #description1");
});

$("#second").click(function(){
  onClick(2, "https://codepen.io/tinat/pen/PKGpQy.html #description2");
});

$("#third").click(function(){
  onClick(3, "https://codepen.io/tinat/pen/PKGpQy.html #description3");
});
```

Comment: No problem. If your HTML is flexible then I would actually go for the solution from @evelyn-ma since it has less repetition and doesn't rely on a global variable in your JS